# How to convert a spatial frequency in a 2D-DFT into the units radians per pixel?

Tags: matlab, fourier-transform, dft, frequency-domain

Let's say I have a 2D image, and I take the discrete Fourier Transform (via FFT) of that image.  In the frequency domain, I get the following image:

[image: 2D DFT]

In this image, let's just assume all the spatial frequencies are zero, except for the selected point at (608, 513).  Now, given the x and y-coordinate of the spatial frequency (note this has been centered via *fftshift*), how can I convert the spatial frequency for this selected pixel into radians per pixel?

**My Guess:** Since the 2D-DFT is centered, our X spatial frequency is 608-513 = 95, and our Y spatial frequency is 513-513 = 0.  Then, we need to multiply by 95 by 2 * pi and divide by N to get radians per pixel?